# Read and write Mat (Opencv) in parallel with OpenMP

Tags: opencv, parallel-processing, openmp

i'm using image processing on a mat in opencv, and i try to speed up the process with openmp by parallellising with openmp

```
Mat *input,*output = ...;
#pragma omp parallel for private(i,j) 
for(i=startvalueX; i<stopvalueX; i++) { 
  for(j=startvalueY; j<stopvalueY; j++) {   
    if(input->at<uchar>(i,j)!=0 && simplePoint(i,j,input) {                         
      output->at<uchar>(i,j)=0;
    }
  }
}
```

simplePoint is a method that grabs neighbours in input, and checks if it meets a predefined neighbourhood in a lookup table (around 15 lines of code).

serially, this program takes 1.56s, in parallel, 3.5s

the difference (using gprof) is

```
  %     cumulative   self             self     total           
time     seconds   seconds   calls  ms/call  ms/call  name          
38.40      0.67     0.33       44     7.50    18.97  _GLOBAL__sub_I__Z10splitImagePcPN2cv3MatES2_
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How many threads are you using? Using too much threads will indeed slows down the code. Also, can you try "schedule(static)" and run again?

Comment: @xis19 with schedule(static), it's still the same speed

Comment: Is it faster if you use the `input.data` and `output.data` pointers instead of the `at()` function? `at()` can be particularly slow in Debug mode.